# inotify not installing in rocky8 linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, inotify

I am trying to install inotify-tools.x86_64 in a rocky8 linux machine. I am getting the following error. Any leads are much appreciated

~yum install inotify-tools.x86_64
Last metadata expiration check: 1:09:43 ago on Thu 19 May 2022 04:50:55 PM UTC.
No match for argument: inotify-tools.x86_64
Error: Unable to find a match: inotify-tools.x86_64

I tried to install it using dnf command but resulted in the same error.

I also tried to install it by cloning it from git but the autogen and configure shell script is not running in rocky8.

Comment: Do you have `epel-8` repos configured & enabled in `/etc/yum/repos.d/` directory?

Comment: No I did not, I installed and enabled epel-8 and it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm confused, is it working after enabling `epel-8` repos or it's failing?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I enabled the epel-8 repo and then the inotify got installed as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, `inotify-tools` is offered by `epel-el-8` packages. If you have it enabled in `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory, you should be able to install by `dnf`/`yum` package manager.

Output from my machine..

```
[factory@docker-tests ~]$ yum info inotify-tools.x86_64
Loaded plugins: product-id, remove-with-leaves, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Repository rhel-7-server-rpms is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository epel-el-7 is listed more than once in the configuration
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
Available Packages
Name        : inotify-tools
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 3.14
Release     : 9.el7
Size        : 51 k
Repo        : epel-el-7
Summary     : Command line utilities for inotify
URL         : http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/
License     : GPLv2
Description : inotify-tools is a set of command-line programs for Linux providing
            : a simple interface to inotify. These programs can be used to monitor
            : and act upon filesystem events.
```